# How to include images in page post API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I keep getting this error message when am attaching images to page post

```
message: '(#10) Application does not have permission for this action'
```

but when am posting message only, it works fine

```
FB.api('PAGE_ID/feed', 'post', {
    message: 'Message is here',
    link: 'https://my_LINK.com',
    "child_attachments": [
        {
            "link": "https://1.jpg",
            "image_hash": "hash1",
            "name": "Some Name",
            "description": "Some description"
        },
        {
            "link": "https://2.jpg",
            "image_hash": "hash2",
            "name": "Some Name",
            "description": "Some description 2"
        }]

}, function (res) {
    if (!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
        return;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to add multi images to a post in facebook, it has to be done in 2 steps as per [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating)

to upload image, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452122/how-to-upload-local-image-to-facebook?noredirect=1#comment103242474_58452122) and to make the post

```
function post_fb_ad(description, ad_images) {

    attached_media = []
    for (var adImg of ad_images) {

        attached_media.push({ media_fbid: adImg.id })
    }

    FB.api('page_id/feed', 'post', {
        message: description,
        attached_media: attached_media,
        access_token: EXD_ACCESS_TOKEN


    }, function (res) {
        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
            return;
        }

        console.log('post id is ', res)

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish to a page, you will need to use a page access token that has `publish_pages` permission which you may be missing.
You can quickly test the request using the [Graph API Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).
You can also use the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) tool to test what permissions your access token has.
Also, note that `publish_pages` permission is [reviewable](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_pages) and needs to be [approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/) before you can use it with the general public. Prior to approval, you can only test it with an app where you are an admin and in a page where you have admin role.