# How to upload local image to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I managed to upload an image to facebook using online URL but, when I try a local image using format `file://path/to/image`I get the error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) url should represent a valid URL","type":"OAuthException","code":100}
```

is it doable ? or am doing it wrong ?

```
async function upload_fb_image(photo) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        FB.api(PAGE_ID + '/photos', 'post', {
            message: 'Message',
            url: LINK_TO_IMAGE,
            published: false,
            caption: 'Ad',
            access_token: EXD_ACCESS_TOKEN
        }).then(data => { resolve(data) })
    })
}
```

**as Form data**

I tried as form data as mentioned in answers ... I receive `ok` response but, the image ID is not returned, I get the below JSON in reponse

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState:
         ReadableState {
           objectMode: false,
           highWaterMark: 16384,
           buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
           length: 25,
           pipes: null,
           pipesCount: 0,
           flowing: null,
           ended: true,
           endEmitted: false,
           reading: false,
           sync: false,
           needReadable: false,
           emittedReadable: false,
           readableListening: false,
           resumeScheduled: false,
           paused: true,
           emitClose: true,
           autoDestroy: false,
           destroyed: false,
           defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
           awaitDrain: 0,
           readingMore: false,
           decoder: null,
           encoding: null },
        readable: true,
        _events:
         [Object: null prototype] {
           prefinish:
            { [Function: prefinish]
              [length]: 0,
              [name]: 'prefinish',
              [prototype]: prefinish { [constructor]: [Circular] } },
           error:
            { [Function]
              [length]: 1,
              [name]: '',
              [prototype]: { [constructor]: [Circular] } } },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState:
         WritableState {
           objectMode: false,
           highWaterMark: 16384,
           finalCalled: false,
           needDrain: false,
           ending: true,
           ended: true,
           finished: true,
           destroyed: false,
           decodeStrings: true,
           defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
           length: 0,
           writing: false,
           corked: 0,
           sync: false,
           bufferProcessing: false,
           onwrite:
            { [Function: bound onwrite] [length]: 1, [name]: 'bound onwrite' },
           writecb: null,
           writelen: 0,
           bufferedRequest: null,
           lastBufferedRequest: null,
           pendingcb: 0,
           prefinished: true,
           errorEmitted: false,
           emitClose: true,
           autoDestroy: false,
           bufferedRequestCount: 0,
           corkedRequestsFree:
            { next: null,
              entry: null,
              finish:
               { [Function: bound onCorkedFinish] [length]: 1, [name]: 'bound onCorkedFinish' } } },
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState:
         { afterTransform:
            { [Function: bound afterTransform] [length]: 2, [name]: 'bound afterTransform' },
           needTransform: false,
           transforming: false,
           writecb: null,
           writechunk: null,
           writeencoding: 'buffer' } },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/photos',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers:
      Headers {
        [Symbol(map)]:
         [Object: null prototype] {
           'x-business-use-case-usage':
            [ '{"1006471116044666":[{"type":"pages","call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]}',
              [length]: 1 ],
           'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', [length]: 1 ],
           'facebook-api-version': [ 'v2.10', [length]: 1 ],
           'strict-transport-security': [ 'max-age=15552000; preload', [length]: 1 ],
           pragma: [ 'no-cache', [length]: 1 ],
           'x-fb-rev': [ '1001316471', [length]: 1 ],
           'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*', [length]: 1 ],
           'cache-control':
            [ 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', [length]: 1 ],
           'x-fb-trace-id': [ 'CSSaQru0iZZ', [length]: 1 ],
           'x-fb-request-id': [ 'AguAWIpbfPySfVvwPjZZBec', [length]: 1 ],
           expires: [ 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', [length]: 1 ],
           'x-fb-debug':
            [ 'NnSTSun7s8VUcMnXu9cUYXQh/7laST0pILTNbAJrS0mtGHGXnQt17fRtyhS8R+RkZWyawJ4meKDWNKT1N+1uBA==',
              [length]: 1 ],
           date: [ 'Sat, 19 Oct 2019 01:31:32 GMT', [length]: 1 ],
           'x-fb-trip-id': [ '1886706526', [length]: 1 ],
           'alt-svc': [ 'h3-23=":443"; ma=3600', [length]: 1 ],
           connection: [ 'close', [length]: 1 ],
           'content-length': [ '25', [length]: 1 ] } },
     counter: 0 } }
```

Comment: see my answer below. btw, that function of yours does not have to be an async function, as you do not use await. for promises, you do not need async.

Answer (score 1):

The url must be a public url, not some url from your local computer. Alternatively, you can use FormData:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
const file = document.getElementById('imageInput').files[0];

fileReader.onloadend = async () => {
    const photoData = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: 'image/jpg'});
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('access_token', pageAccessToken);
    formData.append('source', photoData);
    formData.append('message', 'some status message');

    let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/photos`, {
        body: formData,
        method: 'post'
    });
    response = await response.json();
    console.log(response);
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Source: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/

Comment: for some reason, the above wouldn't get recognized as form-data

Answer (score 0):

finally it was solved using the below method

```
 const formData = {
            access_token: EXD_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            source: fs.createReadStream("path/to/image"),
            published: 'false'
        }

        console.log('sendning request')

        request.post({ url: `https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}/photos`, formData: formData }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', err);
            }

            resolve(body)
        });
```