# How do I upload a photo from my local machine to a Facebook page using the Facebook Graph API (via Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload a photo from my local machine (e.g. a jpg) to a Facebook page I am the admin on, using the Facebook Graph API (using Access VBA).

I can post an image that is on the internet already to the Facebook page, with a message, that works fine.

But I want the file to come from my local machine...

I can't work it out!

This code (VBA) works to upload a JPG that is already on the internet

```
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim boundary As String
    Dim postData As String
    Dim pageID As String, accessToken As String, fileUrl As String, message As String
    pageID = "[My Page ID]"
    accessToken = "[My long-lived Access Token]"
    fileUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png"
    message = "test message"

    boundary = "----------------------------" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyyhhmmss")

    postData = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & _
               "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""message""" & vbCrLf & _
               "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               message & vbCrLf & _
               "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & _
               "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""url""" & vbCrLf & _
               "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               fileUrl & vbCrLf & _
               "--" & boundary & "--"

    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://graph.facebook.com/" & pageID & "/photos?access_token=" & accessToken, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
        .send (postData)

        If .status = 200 Then
            Debug.Print .responseText
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error: " & .status & " - " & .statusText
        End If
    End With
```

This works.

I can't for the life of me work out how to change the photo to be one from my local machine though.

Please note: I have the correct token settings because, as I say, this code above works for a photo that is already on the internet - so my page ID and my access token must be correct.

[My text logical question will be.... how do I upload multiple photos?]

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Not finding VBA example but maybe you will get clue from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452122/how-to-upload-local-image-to-facebook or https://gist.github.com/nseo/2910244

Comment: Sorry I've had a look at these and I just can't see how to make it work in VBA

Comment: This question shows code for converting image to stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344715/excel-vba-get-adodb-stream-from-image-control-not-with-loadfromfile. Maybe relevent. Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391992/how-do-i-upload-jpg-to-my-own-webserver-using-vba-in-access

Answer (score 0):

A URL like this should work:

```
file:///C:/Test/YourImage.jpg
```

Note the forward slashes, though you may get away with backslashes in the filename part.

Comment: This returned an error 400 I'm afraid...

Comment: Yes, June's link is right; either pass the image as a stream, or provide a URL that Facebook can see.

Comment: Yeah, it's the "passing the image as a stream" bit that I just can't work out how to do....

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to get this working:

```
Public Function UploadFileToFacebookPage()

    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim boundary As String
    Dim postData As String
    Dim pageID As String, accessToken As String, fileUrl As String, message As String
    pageID = "[My page ID]"
    accessToken = "[My long-lived access token]"
    
    Dim fileName As String, filePath As String

    filePath = "Z:\Desktop\testimage.jpg"
    fileName = "testimage.jpg"
    message = "test message"

    boundary = "----------------------------" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyyhhmmss")
           
    postData = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""message""" & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & message & vbCrLf

    postData = postData & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""source""; filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & "Content-Type: image/jpeg" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & getBinaryFile(filePath) & vbCrLf
    postData = postData & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf

    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://graph.facebook.com/" & pageID & "/photos?access_token=" & accessToken, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
        .send ToByteArray(postData) ' Convert from Unicode
        

        If .Status = 200 Then
            Debug.Print .ResponseText
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error: " & .Status & " - " & .statusText
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and

```
Function getBinaryFile(filePath) As Variant
  Dim binaryStream As Variant
  Set binaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  binaryStream.Type = 1
  binaryStream.Open
  binaryStream.LoadFromFile filePath
  getBinaryFile = StrConv(binaryStream.Read, vbUnicode) ' Convert to Unicode
  binaryStream.Close
End Function
```

and

```
Function ToByteArray(str As String) As Byte()
    ToByteArray = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```