# How do I upload JPG to my own webserver using VBA in Access?

Tags: php, vba, ms-access

I have some code but I can't see why it doesn't work...

```
Sub UploadJPGWithCURL()
    Dim winHttpReq As Object
    Dim fileData As String
    Dim boundary As String

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim filePath As String
    
    filePath = "Z:\Desktop\testimage.jpg"
    fileName = "testimage.jpg"

    boundary = "----------------------------" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyyhhmmss")
    
    fileData = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    fileData = fileData & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""fileToUpload""; filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbCrLf
    fileData = fileData & "Content-Type: image/jpeg" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    'fileData = fileData & filePath & vbCrLf
    fileData = fileData & getBinaryFile(filePath) & vbCrLf
    fileData = fileData & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf
    
    Debug.Print fileData
    
    Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    winHttpReq.Open "POST", "[THE URL TO MY WEBSERVER PHP PAGE THAT IS GOING TO PROCESS THE UPLOAD]", False
    winHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
    winHttpReq.send (fileData)
    
    If winHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
      Debug.Print winHttpReq.ResponseText
    Else
      Debug.Print "Request failed with status code: " & winHttpReq.Status
    End If
End Sub

Function getBinaryFile(filePath)
  Dim binaryStream
  Set binaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  binaryStream.Type = 1
  binaryStream.Open
  binaryStream.LoadFromFile filePath
  getBinaryFile = binaryStream.Read
  binaryStream.Close
End Function
```

On the server, PHP, the $_FILES array is giving an error code 3 for this file, which seems to be partial upload....? (I get this if a Print_r the $_FILES array at the top of the php code....

```
Array
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => testimage.jpg
            [full_path] => testimage.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 3
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the binary content of the file and the data sent like this:

```
Function getBinaryFile(filePath) As Variant
  Dim binaryStream As Variant
  Set binaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  binaryStream.Type = 1
  binaryStream.Open
  binaryStream.LoadFromFile filePath
  getBinaryFile = StrConv(binaryStream.Read, vbUnicode) ' Convert to Unicode
  binaryStream.Close
End Function
```

And when sending the data:

Create this function:

```
Function ToByteArray(str As String) As Byte()
    ToByteArray = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

And use it like this:

```
winHttpReq.send ToByteArray(fileData) ' Convert from Unicode
```

Tested and it worked:

```
Array
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => sample.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => J:\tmp\php827.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3287
        )
)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the same error in the PHP $_FILES with your updated code

Comment: @ChrisLydon sorry I edited the answer, now it should work